# Shibboleth: add IDP and SP entityID to attribute value

Tags: shibboleth

I have an attribute value (identifier) that looks like following: `5678`

I would like to add `entityID` of both `IDP` and the recipient `SP` to get the (targeted) attribute value: `idp-entity-id!sp-entity-id!5678`

I tried using `xsi:type="Template"`:

```
<AttributeDefinition xsi:type="Template" ...>
    <Dependency ref="myDataConnector" />
    <SourceAttribute>mySourceAttribute</SourceAttribute>
    <AttributeEncoder xsi:type="SAML2String" ... />
    <Template>${resolutionContext.getAttributeIssuerID()}!${resolutionContext.getAttributeRecipientID()}!${mySourceAttribute}</Template>
</AttributeDefinition>
```

However it looks like `resolutionContext` is not accessible inside of `AttributeDefinition` `Template` because I receive a value that looks like this:

```
resolutionContext.getAttributeIssuerID()!resolutionContext.getAttributeRecipientID()!5678
```

What would be the correct way to add these two entityID to the existing attribute value to get it in the format `idp-entity-id!sp-entity-id!5678`?

---

Shibboleth version: `3.3`, planned upgrade to `3.4`.